# Print only numeric value from a string example "(0 results returned)" in Selenium

Tags: selenium, split

When executing Selenium script, I got results as "(0 results returned)", but I want to go for next step if the record exists or not. If there is 0 then record does not exist. If it is more then 0 then the records are available. So I want to print only numeric values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract number using regex. For example,

```
String result="(0 results returned)";
String numericOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```